# Add bibliography to ToC without changing bibliography style

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%-> For bibliography
\RequirePackage[num, overcite]{abntex2cite}

%-> Generate dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

%-> Change section numbering style
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

%-> Add References to ToC
% \RequirePackage[nottoc, section]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-2]

And here, in this paragraph, I need to cite someone~\cite{ClrT10ca}. This reference will appear in the bibliography area below.

\section{Section two}
\lipsum[3]



\bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

with bib file content

```
@article{ClrT10ca,
    author = {Tracey M. Clarke and James R. Durrant},
    title = {Charge Photogeneration in Organic Solar Cells},
    journal = {Chemical Reviews},
    volume = {110},
    number = {11},
    pages = {6736-6767},
    year = {2010}    }
```

If I uncomment the `\RequirePackage[nottoc, section]{tocbibind}`, the bibliography appears in the ToC, but its configuration suffers a lot of modification in the Bibliography section.

My question is: *how can I add the Bibliography to Table of Contents without changing the bibliography style?*

Comment: The bibliography style **does not change**. Also, don't use `RequirePackage`, use `\usepackage` in the main `.tex` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bibliography style does not change. What caused the change in **heading** style was the option `section` in `tocbibind`. Also, don't use `RequirePackage`, use `\usepackage` in the main `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%-> For bibliography
\usepackage[num, overcite]{abntex2cite}

%-> Generate dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

%-> Change section numbering style
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

%-> Add References to ToC
\usepackage[nottoc%, section
]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-2]

And here, in this paragraph, I need to cite someone~\cite{ClrT10ca}. This reference will appear in the bibliography area below.

\section{Section two}
\lipsum[3]



\bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your MWE and as you say the Bibliography heading gets changed when using your use of `tocbibind`. Try using

```
\usepackage[nottoc, chapter]{tocbibind}
```

instead.

However I see you are using the `report` class where one normally uses `\chapter` before `\section`. If, as expected, you had `\chapter`s in your MWE then

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

would make everything consistent.

If you don't want to use `\chapter` then use a class, like `article`, which does not expect them.

Comment: How does your answer differ from mine? Or maybe we posted at the same time?

Comment: I prepared my answer but when I posted it yours was there although it hadn't been when I started. Our answers do provide slightly different information.